# ListContourPlot is blocking my geometry

Tags: plotting

I have a Navier-Stokes solution for a flow past a cylinder. I have attached the DAT file. The columns in the DAT file contain the x,y,u,v,p data, respectively. The DAT file can be obtained from our attachment repository [here](https://raw.github.com/stackmma/Attachments/master/data_2571_187.txt).

I am trying to make *Mathematica* plot a contour plot that looks like this for velocity and pressure

[image: Velocity field]

[image: Pressure]

But when I use the following to plot my u,v,p fields, the contours erase my geometry. This is what I have done so far:

```
Data = Import[
   "https://raw.github.com/stackmma/Attachments/master/data_2571_187.txt",
   "Table", "IgnoreEmptyLines" -> True];
x = Data[[All, 1]];
y = Data[[All, 2]];
u = Data[[All, 3]];
v = Data[[All, 4]];
p =  Data[[All, 5]];
gridsolution = Transpose[{x, y}];
velocityu = Transpose[{x, y, u}];
velocityv = Transpose[{x, y, v}];
pressure = Transpose[{x, y, p}];
ListContourPlot[velocityu, PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 99, 
ContourStyle -> {None}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "u(x,y)", 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
ListContourPlot[velocityv, PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 99, 
ContourStyle -> {None}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "v(x,y)", 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
ListContourPlot[pressure, PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 99, 
ContourStyle -> {None}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "P(x,y)", 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"} ]
```

This results in the following figures:

[image: u]
[image: v]
[image: pressure]

How can I make my velocity and pressure plot look like the COMSOL plots above? *Mathematica* doesn't understand that there is a cylinder in the middle, but just overwrites the geometry with contours.

Comment: I can't see the .dat file. Am I missing something?

Comment: if its the visual effect you are after it would be straightforward to add a white disc at the center?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Revisited answer after your data was made available

After you made your data available an easier solution came to my mind.

```
pressure = Import[
  "https://raw.github.com/stackmma/Attachments/master/data_2571_187.txt",
  "Table"][[All, {1, 2, 5}]];

Graphics[{Hue[#5], Tooltip[Point[{#1, #2}], #5]} & @@@ data]
```

[image]

I included a tooltip so you can inspect the values of your data. As you see the values are positive in the regions you are interested in. Therefore, one very simple approach is to define the `PlotRange` accordingly:

```
ListContourPlot[pressure, Contours -> 20, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {10^-6, Automatic}}, Mesh -> All,
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

The same can be achieve even simpler with `RegionFunction` (I switch to `ListDensityPlot` as explained in the *Old answer* below)

```
ListDensityPlot[pressure, PlotRange -> All, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, z > 0], 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

If you want a more perfect circle in the middle, you should extract the radius of the inner circle as described in the very end of this article

```
With[{minradius = Min[Norm /@ pressure[[All, {1, 2}]]]},
 ListDensityPlot[pressure, PlotRange -> All, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Norm[{x, y}] > minradius], 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
 ]
```

Therefore, opposed to what I explain in the next section, for your specific data there is no need for an `Interpolation`. I'm sorry that this answer is such a mess but without your data in the first place it was more guessing.

### Old answer

To explain what happens let's consider a simple example. I'm creating a list of tuples $\{\{x_1,y_1,p_1\},\{x_2,y_2,p_2\},\ldots\}$ randomly distributed but sparing out the inner circle like your data:

```
data = Last@Last@Reap@Table[
      With[{p = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 2]},
       If[Norm[p] < 1 && Norm[p] > .2, 
        Sow@Append[p, Sin[Times @@ p]]]], {10000}];

Graphics[{Hue[#3], Point[{#1, #2}]} & @@@ data]
```

[image]

I don't know whether your data is on a regular grid but that's not the important thing right now.

First of all, what you want is probably not a *contour plot* but a *density plot*. Let us try a simple `ListDensityPlot` using `Mesh->All` to see what happens:

```
ListDensityPlot[data, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

As you see, in order to create a colorized area *Mathematica* has triangulated your data points. Now here comes the clue: How should *Mathematica* know that you want to leave out the center? It just thinks that you probably have not many measured points there and therefore it does, what it is doing for the rest of the area: It *interpolates*. And since the center is surrounded by measured points, this is pretty easy. (This is opposed to outside the circle, where interpolation is not possible!)

To solve your problem, I would suggest you use `Interpolation` to interpolate your data, use `DensityPlot` to draw it and the option `RegionFunction` to exclude whatever region you don't want in your plot:

```
With[{ip = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1]},
 func[p : {x_, y_}] := If[Norm[p] < 1 && Norm[p] > .2, ip[x, y], 0]
 ]

DensityPlot[func[{x, y}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> Hue, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, Norm[{x, y}] < .98 && Norm[{x, y}] > .2],
 PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 1]
```

[image]

Note that `ListDensityPlot` has the `RegionFunction` option too, but there is a pitfall hidden. `ListContourPlot` seems to use not really a *region*. Instead it just does not take data points outside outside the region into account. This gives surprising results. Try yourself.

**Side note:** If you don't know the values of your inner circle, you can just calculate it by using `Norm` and `Min` on all your `{x,y}` pairs.